# How one can get a field auto loaded with node title by passing nid

Tags: entities, nodes, views

How one can get a field auto loaded with node title by passing nid. I mean instead of getting the selectllist of all available title i want it to be auto loaded with corresponding node title.

NOTE: I have passed nid to that content type. Now have to fetch the corresponding node title into a field.

Thanks in advance ,
Manju

Comment: Are you opposed to using jquery for this?  If not you may have to do a form_alter to grab the args() value and change the default value to whatever the NID is

Comment: I am new to drupal and so have only basic knowledge about it. Could you pls elaborate the steps for it . Thanks

Comment: We are not using jquery.. Is there a way where I can get it with the existing functionalities without need for coding?

Comment: Is this on content type field or what form is it?

Comment: yes it is on content type field only ....

Comment: Are you on a node form ?

Answer (score 1):

[Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) might solve your problem.

> The Prepopulate module allows fields in most forms to be pre-populated from the $_REQUEST variable.
>
> For example, the following URL,
>
> `http://www.example.com/node/add/blog?edit[title]=this is the title`
>
> will automatically fill the Title field on a new blog post with the words "this is the title". Any field can be prepopulated this way, including taxonomy and CCK fields. You can prepopulate more than one field at a time as well. Prepopulate is excellent for creating bookmarklets. For examples on usage for all of these cases, please read the USAGE.txt file that comes with the module or you can read the online handbook page.

Answer (score 1):

The [Node Reference URL Widget](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) worked well for my issue. I got the field autopopulated using the value from URL.

Manju